# Grouping objects by date to put in a graph JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm doing a little project that takes data from facebook about conversations in JSON and creates a graph with dates on X axis and message number on Y. 
Now I have no idea how to group messages text by date, which is stored in object as well.

I wanted to use

```
stream().collect().GroupingBy(//..
```

to put data in a `Map<LocalDate,List<Message>>` but ideally it would be `Map<LocalDate,Integer>` mapping the date to the number of messages on that date.
Or if there is some better solution so it would be easier later to use it for graphical interpretation I'm open to suggestions.

```java
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Message {
    private String sender_name;
    private Timestamp timestamp_ms;
    private String content;

}
```

```java
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Conversation {
    private ArrayList<Message> messages;
}
```

```java
 public static void readData(String path) throws IOException {

        byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Conversation conversation = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Conversation.class);
        groupByDate(conversation);

    }

    public static void groupByDate(Conversation conv){
        HashMap<LocalDate,Message> countMap =  conv.getMessages().stream().collect(groupingBy(conv.getMessages().::/*?*/));

    }
```

Comment: I meant Integer as a number of messages counted for the specific day.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details about the desired results in the GUI I cannot suggest better alternatives, but assuming a `Map<LocalDate, Long>` is also ok, you could use an overloaded version of the `groupingBy` method:

```
Map<LocalDate, Long> countMap =  conv.getMessages().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             (Function<Message, LocalDate>) message -> message.getTimestamp().toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate(),
             Collectors.counting()));
```